# Add a fixed discount value to an order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

By default, WooCommerce does not enable a fixed amount discount such as $5 off, $10 off, or $15 off, etc, from the cart's total.

How can I give such a discount when creating a new order from the admin?

I have looked at many plugins but none enable this type of discount.

NOTE:
The discount should be usable without any conditions and I should be able to apply it to any order I feel like discounting.

Comment: its possible with WooCommerce itself

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any plugins for this as Woocommerce handles the functionality out of the box. Goto `Woocommerce > Coupons` and set the discount type to "fixed cart discount". Make sure that coupons are enabled via `Woocommerce > Settings > Checkout` (select the "enable the use of coupons" checkbox) beforehand though.